# Java, IntelliJ, download dependency with Maven (and LanguagetTool)

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm trying to get LanguageTool to work together with Java. I have IntelliJ installed and created a new Maven Project.

Under Settings->Maven->Importing i checked the box "Import Maven Projects automatically".

I then added LanguageTool as a dependency for the project. My POM-file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>test.languagetools</groupId>
    <artifactId>LanguageToolsTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.languagetoo</groupId>
                <artifactId>language-en</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

My main class is from the example on the API page for LanguageTool ([Link](http://wiki.languagetool.org/java-api))

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JLanguageTool langTool = new JLanguageTool(new BritishEnglish());
//langTool.activateDefaultPatternRules();  -- only needed for LT 2.8 or earlier
        List<RuleMatch> matches = langTool.check("A sentence with a error in the Hitchhiker's Guide tot he Galaxy");

        for (RuleMatch match : matches) {
            System.out.println("Potential error at line " +
                    match.getLine() + ", column " +
                    match.getColumn() + ": " + match.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Suggested correction: " +
                    match.getSuggestedReplacements());
        }
    }
}
```

But i get error that the compiler cant find the classes. I never used Maven before, is there something else that I should do to download the libraries?

```
Error:(3, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class JLanguageTool
  location: class main
Error:(3, 38) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class JLanguageTool
  location: class main
Error:(3, 56) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class BritishEnglish
  location: class main
Error:(5, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class List
  location: class main
Error:(5, 14) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class RuleMatch
  location: class main
Error:(7, 14) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class RuleMatch
  location: class main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like part of the problem is a simple spelling error in your dependency stanza: `<group>org.languagetoo</group>` should be `<group>org.languagetool</group>`

Also, `<dependencyManagement>` does not mean the same thing as `<dependency>`. I think you want the latter.

Comment: Yes, that seemed to be the problem. I took away the <dependencyManagement> and kept everything inside and then it worked fine.